# How to implement lightning app <design:component> on the components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

> "Failed to save undefined: markup://c:Calendar:7,111: Invalid
>   attribute "name": Source "

I've followed the tutorial on this link [Tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm), when I try to save I get an error.

My sample components structure:

```
<aura:attribute name="greeting" type="String" default="Hello" />
<aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" default="World" />
<div style="box">
    <span class="greeting">{!v.greeting}</span>, {!v.subject}!
</div>

<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" type="picklist" datasource="Hello,Hola,Bienvenue,Shalom" />

</design:component>
```

Comment: Ahh, I already found it. Wrong structure. design:component must be in design section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, I already found it. Wrong structure of component. `design:component` must be in design section under component properties Component, Controller, Helper, Style, etc.